# How to make an object go to specific spots in order Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have it set so that the boomerang goes to a random point. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Patrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    public float range;
    private float distToPlayer;

    public Transform player;
  
    public Transform[] moveSpots;
    private int randomSpot;

    private float waitTime;
    public float startWaitTime;
    
    void Start()
    {
        waitTime = startWaitTime;
        randomSpot = Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length);
    }       

    void Update()
    {                                             //start            //finish
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position) < 0.2f)
        {
            if (waitTime <= 0)
            {
                randomSpot = Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length);
                waitTime = startWaitTime;
            }
            else
            {
                waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

        distToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

        if (distToPlayer < range)
        {  
            Destroy(gameObject);   
        }  
    }
}
```

So, how can I make it that it goes to one points first, then the other? Help!

Comment: So what exactly is happening instead currently?

Comment: its i bacicaly picking one of the two points and moving the object to it, then picking another and then moving to the next

Comment: it is also waiting 3 seconds before moving to the next point

Comment: Yeah I see that but what is your issue / cause of your question?

Comment: I need that it goes to one of the points first, then the other. Not randomize it

Comment: well, then how about not randomize the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your moveSpots are in order you just need to get rid of your Random operations, and get the next item in the array

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Patrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    public float range;
    private float distToPlayer;

    public Transform player;
  
    public Transform[] moveSpots;
    // Start at index 0
    private int nextSpot = 0;

    private float waitTime;
    public float startWaitTime;
    
    void Start()
    {
        waitTime = startWaitTime;

    }       

    void Update()
    {                                             //start            //finish
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpots[nextSpot].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots[nextSpot].position) < 0.2f)
        {
            if (waitTime <= 0)
            {
                // Set to the next index
                nextSpot ++;
                waitTime = startWaitTime;
            }
            else
            {
                waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

        distToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

        if (distToPlayer < range)
        {  
            Destroy(gameObject);   
        }  
    }
}
```

Then you have to decide what you want to do when you get to the end of your list? Do they stop? Do you go back to the first spot?

```
// If you want to go back to the first spot you could check the length and reset to 0
nextSpot++;
if (nextSpot > moveSpots.Length)
{
    nextSpot = 0;
}
```

Comment: Just one thing, now when I do this it tells me index is outside of bounds array. What does this mean?

Comment: Index out of bounds means that your nextSpot value has gone to a number higher then the number of moveSpots that you have. Did you handle the "what happens when you reach the last spot scenario"?

Comment: yes i did put that, but it did not do anything

Comment: Can you provide your updated code so we can see how you applied that? What is the value of nextSpot when you get index out of bounds? How many moveSpots are in the array?